# Get required data in different variables using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split

I am working on a web-scraping project. I have been able to get the data, but at one point, the data I want is extracted as a string. What will be the correct way to store the required data into different fields/variables (GPA, GMAT, GRE, Location)

Below is the output I am getting:

```
GPA: 3.4 GRE: 317 Round: Round 2 | West
GPA: 3.50 GMAT: 700 Round: Round 3 | Texas
GMAT: 640 Round: Round 3 | Aftica
Round: Round 3 | East Coast
GMAT: 610 Round: Round 2
GPA: 3.22 Round: Round 3 | NYC
GPA: 3.852 GMAT: 720 Round: Round 1 | Northeast
```

Comment: You can use a regular expression to extract the fields.

Comment: Yes, but Little unsure how to get data, when the value isn't mentioned for the specific field. (As third entry has no GPA. Secondly, first has GRE, second has GMAT)

Comment: You can just match all `(\w+): ([\d.]+)` to get all the fields and values. Then loop over all the matches.